Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 130.0.6723.116) in puppeteer
I am trying to take Screenshot a webpage from url given by user. In my local machine everything works fine but when i deploy it on vercel, i am getting this error:-
Error capturing screenshot: Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 130.0.6723.116). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/sbx_user1051/.cache/puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
    at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/var/task/Backend/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserLauncher.js:292:27)
    at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/var/task/Backend/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:210:25)
    at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (/var/task/Backend/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:91:37)
    at async ChromeLauncher.launch (/var/task/Backend/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserLauncher.js:71:28)
    at async screenshot (/var/task/Backend/controllers/getScreenshot.controller.js:17:19)

Here is the full Backend Code which is working correctly in local machine but not on vercel:-
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const path = require('path')
const { v4: uuid } = require('uuid');
const fs = require('fs')

const screenshot = async (req, res) => {
    const url = req.query.url;

    if (!url) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'URL is required' });
    }

    let browser;
    try {

        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        try {
            await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.message.includes('net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED') || err.message.includes('net::ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT')) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid URL' });
            }
            else {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid URL' })
            }
        }

        await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });

        const fileName = `${uuid()}.png`;
        const screenshotPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', fileName);
        await page.screenshot({ path: screenshotPath });

        res.json({ screenshotPath: `/image/${fileName}` });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error capturing screenshot:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to capture screenshot' });
    } finally {
        if (browser) {
            await browser.close();
        }
    }
};

module.exports = screenshot;

I have tried to add .puppeteerrc.cjs file but it did not work. i am getting same error.
const { join } = require('path');

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
    // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
    cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};


Related GH thread

Not Working....
